# Handle redirects, if file is found, htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want users to be redirected from `site1.com/dir/file.zip` to `handler.com/handle.php?file=/dir/file.zip`. After this, if file exists in site1.com, it will be downloaded, if file does not exist, user will be redirected to `site2.com/dir/file.zip` where file will be downloaded.
This is what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !handler\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^111\.111
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(doc|rar|zip|pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://handler.com/handle?=$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: You said you want to redirect to `handler.com/handle.php?file=/path/to/file` but your rule is redirecting you to `handler.com/handle?=/path/to/file`, which is incorrect - they do not match. Use `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://handler.com/handle.php?file=$1 [L,R]`.

Comment: I misstyped when changed domains to handler.com, still, thats not the case.